# Back propogation Algorithm dervivation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation

I am reading the following link : http://blog.manfredas.com/backpropagation-tutorial/ for understanding the derivation of the back propogation algorithm.

[image]

In the step for computing the partial derivative of E with respect to w vector, in step 2, the author has directly replaced hw(xi)-yi as sigmoid(xi.w) in the next step.

How are the two equal?

Answer (score 0):

The derivative wrt to y_i is 0 because it is constant wrt w and in this case the hypothesis h must be the inner product of the weight and input x passed through a sigmoid.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just missed to see this,  don't know how :)